# Using MPMusicPlayerController play a MPMediaItemCollection, how to get the event of at end of playing

Tags: iphone, events, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I'm using the `MPMusicPlayerController` to play `MPMediaItems` in a `MPMediaItemCollection`.  How can I fire an event when the `MPMediaItem`s are done playing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register for `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` notifications:

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handlePlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.musicPlayer];
```

and tell your musicPlayerController to generate those notifications:

```
[self.musicPlayerController beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```

In `handlePlaybackStateChanged:` you can check the `playbackState` property of musicPlayerController:

```
- (void)handlePlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotitication*)notification
{
    if (self.musicPlayerController.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped ||
        self.musicPlayerController.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted ||
        self.musicPlayerController.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```